# I installed the Android WhatsApp app on my Blackberry but some features don't work

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, blackberry

I downloaded an android version of WhatsApp Messenger on my Blackberry Z 10 but I am unable to send any audio or video files. Why? What can I do about it?

Comment: Please give more details like screenshots. Also make sure you've installed the **original** [WhatsApp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp) and not the [fake ones](https://www.phonearena.com/news/Fake-WhatsApp-app-draws-over-one-million-downloads-from-the-Google-Play-Store_id99520).

Comment: @priyansh, being that you officially can't download Android apps on the blackberry os, so if you did it somehow it makes sense that it will not work properly, firstly possible that the Android apps don't see the storage of the phone, and many other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp [announced](https://blog.whatsapp.com/10000617/WhatsApp-support-for-mobile-devices) their decision that the WhatsApp application will no longer support BlackBerry OS and BlackBerry 10 devices, among other devices, by the end of 2016 June 30th, now [updated](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/26000006) to December 31, 2017. BlackBerry devices powered by Android such as BlackBerry PRIV and BlackBerry DTEK50 will continue to be supported.

> Note: Because we will no longer actively develop for these platforms,
>   some features may stop functioning at any time.

So let's assume that sending media files is no longer supported.

If you would like more specific information on what specific WhatsApp functionality will remain on BlackBerry OS and BlackBerry 10 devices, as well as other devices for which WhatsApp has decided to end support, please contact WhatsApp [here](https://www.whatsapp.com/contact).

Further reading [here](https://faq.whatsapp.com/sw/bb10/24983053/).

Comment: BTW if you change the date on the actual phone to before December 2016, WhatsApp will work. But the OP is saying that they downloaded the Android version of WhatsApp. -Probably by "rooting" the device‬ - so that shouldn't be affect by the blackberry shut down

Comment: Nope, changing the date won't help since it is checked server-side! No, they didn't root. No need root access to install the Android version of Whatsapp,  IIRC, BB OS 10.2 made it possible to install android apps on BB  OS.

Answer (score 0):

Now Whatsapp for android is working fine in BB10 devices, to fix these problems you need to install 'WhatsFixer' available in BBWorld.
After installing, you have to execute and follow instructions

https://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/60005088/?lang=en